# symfony 1.x using forms and widgets with database data

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms

I understand that you can achieve the a mulit choice box using something like this

```
public function executeContact($request)
{
  $this->form = new sfForm();
  $this->form->setWidgets(array(
    'name'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
    'email'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default' => 'me@example.com')),
    'subject' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => array('Subject A', 'Subject B', 'Subject C'))),
    'message' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(),
  ));
}
```

to produce something like this

[image]

But instead using a hard coded array set of data, how would one go about grabing database data. I have bee playing around with this for a while with schemas and all I can see to be able to grab is is the ID of a table. Anything im doing wrong?

Comment: Is it symfony 1.x series?

Comment: oh yes im sorry ill remove the tag

Comment: Not sure about Symfony 1.x, but if you want load DB data in a select form field, so option attribute should be ID or primary key of table row. Also, I guessing you aren't using Doctrine entities.

Comment: Ill remove that as well, sorry. Um I am not sure exactly what you mean by that. Sorry this system is outdated and its all I have to work with

Comment: What the "part" you don't undestand? Can you please be somewhat more clear. what trouble/issue are you getting?

Comment: Also, is this current app using propel or doctrine lib?

Comment: So im trying to base the sfWidgetFormChoice off category names in my database. right now its something like this 

sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Category')), and its only retrieving the table rows 'ID', It is using the doctrine library

Comment: In original question you are not talking about "sfWidgetFormChoice". Anyway, have you set the *method* option in method options? Your Category entity has any __toString() Method? Maybe it is the reason for the issue.

Comment: I used a simple example from the symfony manual, so future people that come across have some direction. By method options do you mean sfWidgetFormChoice("Method options ") or do you mean a seperate file with method options? Thats what I don't understand. There is no __toString() Method.

Comment: I mean something like this: `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Category', 'method' => 'getCategoryName'))`

Comment: No I have not. Is that the correct syntax 'method'?

Comment: Yes, it is. `method` is one of sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice options. By default `__toString()` method is used in order to show values on select form field. When you want to show a specific table collum value in the select field, you shoud use  `method` option. Has Category class any `__toString()` method? I've asked to you before, but you haven't answered me yet.

Comment: I did answer it in one of my comments saying no if you look up :), but anyway, No not to my knowledge I have not set any __toString() method. Should I set this __toString() method.

Comment: I'm so sorry, you're right regarding related `__toString()` question. Well... let's start again... What `Category` property value do you want to show in selectet form field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101140/discussion-between-seus-and-felipsmartins).

Answer (score 2):

First get the data using an already constructed model from your schema as so;

```
'category' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'MyCategoryTable'))
```

I Found out that in order to retrieve certain values from tables in a database, you must follow default naming conventions when generating your tables in your migration. Where I went wrong was naming a column `'Category'`. Instead it must be `'name'`. I am yet still to gain further information on retrieving data using custom column names